# React native axios call to node js backend

Tags: node.js, react-native, axios, expo

We're developing a react native app with a node.js server running express on the backend.

We're making the call from the UI to node.js using `axios.get('http://ipv4address:3001/apicall')`.

We've installed the `expo-cli` and are trying to run the app from Expo Go on our phones. The LAN version works fine for the developer who has started the server and the UI, but when he changes it to Tunnel mode to share the link, we get a Promise Reject error when the axios call is made from our phones on Expo Go.

How do you share the app with other people who are not on the same LAN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do you share the app with other people who are not on the same LAN?

You can try [expo-snack](https://snack.expo.io/)

Also you can import code there from git repository too.

Click on three dots beside create folder icon to open this menu
[image: Click on three dots beside create folder icon to open this menu]